# Wikipedia Search bar error: "Can't bind to *ngFor" (Angular2 / HTML / Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I'm basically trying to create a search bar that searches through data then displays that data (through a filter based on the input of the search box after clicking a button) (either from wikipedia or just local fake data, it doesn't matter)

This error has been posted many times in a different question but the context of the solution was too different to help me.

Here is the screenshot for what the error looks like:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9olZC.png)

Here is the full project (without the nodes_modules folder):

https://www.dropbox.com/s/kxq1qgfhh8huudz/FullProject.zip?dl=0

Code with the error (wiki.component.ts):

```
import { Component }        from 'angular2/core';
import { JSONP_PROVIDERS }  from 'angular2/http';
import { Observable }       from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { WikipediaService } from './wikipedia.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'Wikithing',
  template: `
    <h1>Wikipedia Demo</h1>
    <p><i>Fetches after each keystroke</i></p>
    <input #term (keyup)="search(term.value)"/>
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let item of items | async">{{item}}</li>
    </ul>
  `,
  providers:[JSONP_PROVIDERS, WikipediaService]
})
export class WikiComponent {
  constructor (private wikipediaService: WikipediaService) {}
  items: Observable<string[]>;
  search (term: string) {
    this.items = this.wikipediaService.search(term);
  }
}
```

Error in text format:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
angular2.dev.js:384 Angular 2 is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
angular2.dev.js:23935 EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Unexpected token | at column 25 in [ngFor let item of items | async] in WikiComponent@5:10 ("
    <input #term (keyup)="search(term.value)"/>
    <ul>
      <li [ERROR ->]*ngFor="let item of items | async">{{item}}</li>
    </ul>
  "): WikiComponent@5:10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `#item` instead `let item` because you have installed angular 2.0.0-beta.15.

```
<li *ngFor="#item of items | async">{{item}}</li>
```

See also https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-beta17-2016-04-28

Comment: So I changed it and got an error (here is screenshot https://www.dropbox.com/s/hu19k0yxocn9xso/screenthing99.png?dl=0  )  and the one line of code was changed to: "    <li *ngFor="let #item of #items | async">{{#item}}</li>"